# Appending data to a Google Sheet using Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have 3 different tables I'm looking to directly push to 3 separate tabs in a Google Sheet. I set up the GSpread connection and that's working well. I started to adjust my first print statement into what I thought would append the information to Tab A (waveData), but no luck.

I'm looking to append the information to the FIRST blank row in a tab.  Basically, so that the data will be ADDED to what is already in there.

I'm trying to use append_rows to do this, but am hitting a "gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at 'data.values' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue).

I'm really new to this, just thought it would be a fun project to evaluate wave sizes in NJ across all major surf spots, but really in over my head (no pun intended).

Any thoughts?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('152qSpr-4nK9V5uHOiYOWTWUx4ojjVNZMdSmFYov-n50')
waveData = sh.get_worksheet(0)
tideData = sh.get_worksheet(1)
lightData = sh.get_worksheet(2)
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# lightData.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


id_list = [
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
    '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
    '/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/',
    '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
    '/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/',
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    '/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/',

]

for x in id_list:
    waveData.append_rows(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)
                         [2].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]].to_json(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
    # print(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[0])
    # print(pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[1])
```

Comment: If `to_json` is a method, you need `to_json()` (potentially with arguments passed).

Comment: Wow - thank you, that fixed the JSON issue, but didn't solve my overall problem. Step closer though!

Comment: About `I have 3 different tables I'm looking to directly push to 3 separate tabs in a Google Sheet.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your 3 sheets of `waveData`, `tideData`, `lightData` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: I would recommend you to use pygsheets https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the response - there really is no relationship between the 3.  When I scrape with IMPORTHTML into Google sheets, those are just Tables at the locations 0,1, and 2.  I'm basically just trying to have an output of each table on a separate tab

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your reply and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> there really is no relationship between the 3. When I scrape with IMPORTHTML into Google sheets, those are just Tables at the locations 0,1, and 2. I'm basically just trying to have an output of each table on a separate tab

I understood that you wanted to retrieve the values with `pd.read_html(requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com' + x).text)[2].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]]` from `id_list`, and wanted to put the values to a sheet in Google Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

At `append_rows`, it seems that JSON data cannot be directly used. In this case, it is required to use a 2-dimensional array. And, I'm worried about the value of `NaN` in the datafarame. When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this sample, all values are put into a sheet.

```py
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('152qSpr-4nK9V5uHOiYOWTWUx4ojjVNZMdSmFYov-n50')
waveData = sh.get_worksheet(0)

id_list = [
    "/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/",
    "/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/",
    "/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/",
    "/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/",
    "/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/",
    "/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/",
    "/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/",
    "/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/",
]

# I modified the below script.
res = []
for x in id_list:
    df = pd.read_html(requests.get("http://magicseaweed.com" + x).text)[2].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]].fillna("")
    values = [[x], df.columns.values.tolist(), *df.values.tolist()]
    res.extend(values)
    res.append([])

waveData.append_rows(res, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, the retrieved values are put into the 1st sheet as follows. In this sample modification, the path and a blank row are inserted between each data. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Modified script 2:

In this sample, each value is put into each sheet.

```py
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('152qSpr-4nK9V5uHOiYOWTWUx4ojjVNZMdSmFYov-n50')

id_list = [
    "/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/",
    "/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/",
    "/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/",
    "/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/",
    "/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/",
    "/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/",
    "/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/",
    "/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/",
]

obj = {e.title: e for e in sh.worksheets()}
for e in id_list:
    if e not in obj:
        obj[e] = sh.add_worksheet(title=e, rows="1000", cols="26")

for x in id_list:
    df = pd.read_html(requests.get("http://magicseaweed.com" + x).text)[2].iloc[:9, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15]].fillna("")
    values = [df.columns.values.tolist(), *df.values.tolist()]
    obj[x].append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, the sheets are checked and created with the sheet names of the values in `id_list`, and each value is put to each sheet.

#### Reference:

- [append_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.0/api.html?highlight=append_rows#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_rows)

Comment: YOU'RE AMAZING!!! I really don't know how you do it! I'm going to play with this a bit - it's exactly what I need, I Just have some other ideas with it I want to try out. Thank you so much!